# z-index not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

Please see the screenshot below. I have a jQuery menu and an iframe that loads a PDF document. In Chrome and Firefox this works perfectly and the menu appears over the top of the iframe. I have a `z-index: 2` on the menu and a `z-index: -1` on the iframe.

Any ideas of how to fix this in IE?

[image]

EDIT: jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hkA2v/1/

Comment: The fiddle is incomplete; needs an `iframe` or something to show the z-index conflict.

Comment: @JonathanSampson sorry about that. I just updated it.

Comment: still I don't have an answer but want to make a point. the issue is because of PDF file in iframe not just because of iframe. if you open a HTML file in iframe all works fine in all browser.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the Adobe PDF web viewer that opens up. I believe IE opens it on top of IE instead of as part of the page hence making the entire page appear behind the Adobe PDF web viewer.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `position:relative;` on `iframe`.

```
iframe{
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: IE is very picky with z-index but position:relative should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly related to this specific issue.
But people, who are struggling with z-index similar issues in IE9 might consider adding a transparent background in some cases.

Because in IE the element with a link must have a background in order to be click-able. Otherwise the mouse ‘sees right through it’.

```
background: url(transparent.gif);
```

Source: [Forum Post](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?67762-Simple-Controls-Internet-Explorer-9-Z-Index-issue)

Comment: I was reluctant to follow this advice, but it did the trick. I used a paint.net and I made the initial white-image big enough (2000x1500) by resizing it. Then I selected it all and cut it. There I got a transparent image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all elements with z-index are siblings of the same parent. If you start nesting elements inside elements and apply new z-index properties to those children, the z-index will start from the parent's z-index, not any z-index properties set before the parent.

IE is very picky with z-index.